# Add sprites with different sizes

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I need to add sprites of different sizes to my forge viewer project.

As far as I know, I cannot call `dataVizExtn.addViewables(viewableData)` multiple times. Considering that sprite size is set on `viewableData` level, what is the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DataViz extensions currently only support a single size setting for all sprites, mainly to keep the rendering of large number of sprites as efficient as possible.

If you want more control over the individual sprites, you could use "lower level" primitives instead, and display the sprites with your own `THREE.PointCloud` and `THREE.ShaderMaterial` objects.